# Basics of Convolutional layer in CNN

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have problem in understanding the equation and theory of Convolution layer from this [paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7486259} 
It is said in the paper that:

[image]

Anyone, please help me to understand the theory and equation give.

I have rephrased that with my understanding. Please let me know if it's not correct or missed anything.
[image]

Comment: Check this site http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/ and wikipedia for clearer explanations. They have some figures that make that paragraph much easier to understand.

Comment: Pls can you check the equation is it correct? Yes i followed these tutorials just stuck with the equation

Comment: not exactly. The output has either the same size of the input (with zero padding, in your case N x N) or like in the text you quote, some other size, depending on the size of the convolution kernel, but not k x k. Please go carefully through the link I provided you.

Comment: It may seem unrelated, but when implementing CNN, this link helped me understand it better, and also how to implement convolutions efficiently (for CNNs). https://petewarden.com/2015/04/20/why-gemm-is-at-the-heart-of-deep-learning/